# How to use VUEJS in Django WITHOUT npm/nodes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, vuejs2

I have a huge problem. Please do not judge if it is obvious for you, but I did not develop in JS for years.

So here is the context: I have a Django Rest API (which works fine) with Django Rest Framework. The aim of my app is to use `VueJS` as frontend (and so, execute API Calls). BUT here a constraint: I cannot use `npm/node`, but only import the scripts in my Django server (in `/static` obviously) and inport them in the `index.html` file thanks to the Django template render. Imports works fine, but only these imports (I had to take care to change VueJS delimiter because they are in conflict with Django ones).

Anyway, I want to use VuesJS components to store each resource instance and, as my colleague asked me, see/check if we could implement a generic routing (I instantly thought yes with `vue-router` which was well imported as well). But I have issues while I try to create separate files for the router and the components: I always have import issues.

So to ask a concise question: Is it possible to make Django and VueJS work together without node and npm ? And so, can someone give me hints on how to separate the concerns (as in python or any programming language) in js in order to finally import them in the `index.html` (or import a `main.js` file which references the other scripts and execute the business logic)

If it is not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask me precisions, eg: update this post ... I am desperate guys ^^

Comment: ` I always have import issues` share your _issues_ details maybe?

Comment: Yes you can. You can include the script like good old jquery and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `CDN` for `Vuejs`?

You would include this script in your `index.html`:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>`

[The documention shows the installation guides for CDN, npm, and CLI methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN)

This guy does a pretty good job at piecing them together: [Build an app with vuejs and django](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-an-app-with-vuejs-and-django-part-one)